# What do Option Strict and Option Explicit do?

Tags: .net, vb.net, option-strict, option-explicit

I saw this post:

> Typos…  Just use option strict and explicit please..  during one software development project, which I was on as a consultant, they were getting ridiculous amounts of errors everywhere… turned out the developer couldn’t spell and would declare variables with incorrect spelling.. no big deal, until you use the correct spelling when you’re assigning a value to it…  and  you had option explicit off.  Ouch to them…"

What is `Option Strict` and `Option Explicit` anyway? I have googled it up but can't get the idea (because mostly it's Visual Basic, I'm doing PHP).

Comment: `Option Explicit` is perfectly described in the other answers.
I just wanted to let people know that `Option Strict` does not seem to be supported any more. See : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338155(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: @Olivier: option strict is still with us, the way back machine shows the page you referenced not having an option strict listed for a 2013 crawl, but that must have simply been an over sight, it’s been there all along, and there’s no sign of it going away.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

`Option Explicit` means that all variables must be declared.  See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-explicit-statement).  Without this, you can accidentally declare a new variable just by misspelling another variable name.  This is one of those things that cause a lot of grief as you're trying to debug VB programs and figure out why your program isn't working properly.  In my opinion, this shouldn't even be an option - it should always be on.

`Option Strict` "restricts implicit data type conversions to only widening conversions".  See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement).  With this option enabled, you can't accidentally convert one data type to another that is less precise (e.g. from an `Integer` to a `Byte`).  Again, an option that should be turned on by default.

Comment: Option Explicit off for shorter programs saves the development time and energy of thinking up and typing in data types.

Comment: @DougNull No, `Option Explicit` has nothing to do with data types. `Dim` could always be used to declare a variable without specifying its type. With `Option Explicit off` you may additionally declare a variable by simply starting to use it. So if you misspell a previous variable, you're declaring new one: that's evil.

Answer (score 38):

### TL;DR

`Option Strict` and `Option Explicit` help you to catch *potential* and *actual* errors at **design time**, rather than your code compiling and failing at **runtime**. You should switch *both* `On`.

Option Strict and Option Explicit are Off by default. To switch them on:

Option Strict
`Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB defaults -> Option Strict`. Set it to `On`.

Option Explicit
`Tools -> Options -> Editor -> Require Variable Declaration`. tick it.

### Option Explicit

With **Option Explicit Off** you don't have to declare (Dim) a variable before using it:

`a = 123 'a is automatically declared as an Integer`

This becomes dangerous when you declare a variable in one place and think you are using it later but mis-type it:

```
Dim counter As Integer = 0
'some lines later...
countr = 55 'This creates a new variable called countr
```

Or even worse, you assign a value to a variable that you *think* is in scope, but it isn't and you end up declaring a new variable with the same name but differing scope.

With a lot of code or long methods these can be easy to miss so you should always switch it on to prevent these sorts of issues.

### Option Strict

With **Option Strict Off** you can implicitly convert a datatype to a narrowing type with no error:

```
Dim d As Double = 999.99
Dim s As Single = d 'No error with Option Strict Off
```

For these cases Option Strict serves as a warning to the developer to make sure that the double value should never exceed `Single.MaxValue`.

You can also assign an Enum to the incorrect value with no error. The following is a real example of this:

[image]

The variable should have been set to `EOpticalCalStates.FAILED` (24), in fact it sets the State to a value of 4 which is equivalent to `EOpticalCalStates.ALI_HOR`.

Something like this is not easy to spot.

Therefore you should always have Option Strict on by default. This setting *should* have been set on as default, but Microsoft decided to leave it off to increase backwards compatibility (which with hindsight was a mistake IMO).

---

If you have started a project before setting the default for new projects, you will need to use:

"Project" menu -> " Properties..." item -> "Compile" tab -> set "Option strict" to "On".

Comment: `Option Explicit` is on by default. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/311329/option-explicit-and-option-strict-in-visual-basic-net-and-in-visual-ba

Answer (score 6):

Find details here:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311329

> The Option Explicit statement
>
> By
> default, the Visual Basic .NET or
> Visual Basic compiler enforces
> explicit variable declaration, which
> requires that you declare every
> variable before you use it. To change
> this default behavior, see the Change
> the Default Project Values section.
>
> The Option Strict statement
>
> By
> default, the Visual Basic .NET or
> Visual Basic compiler does not enforce
> strict data typing. To change this
> default behavior, see the Change the
> Default Project Values section.